# Cycle Graph check Coq

Tags: graph-theory, coq

Can someone point me to a graph theory library in Coq with ready to use check whether a Graph is Cycle Graph or not. If there is no existing implementation of the above, a library with implementation of vertex degree and connectedness will also do.
I have been exploring library with links below which has graph implementation and connectedness as well,
I couldn't find check on cyclic graph or degree of Vertex related implementation.

[TOC of library](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.pous/covece/graphs/current/toc.html)

[Project Homepage of library](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.pous/covece/graphs/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an explicit study of an algorithm to detect cycles in https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02167236

There are a few interesting aspects: 1/ this is a study of an algorithm working with mutable memory, 2/ the study also includes an analysis of execution costs.

Comment: Hi @yves I will go through the mentioned study. Though I have one quick concern, which is having cycles within graph is weeker property compared to graph itself being Cycle Graph. So even if detect cycles in graph detects a cycle it may not mean the Graph to be Cycle Graph. But still the answer is quite helpful as I have better direction now.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "a Cycle graph".  Do you mean a graph is exactly one cycle and all vertices participating to the cycle?

Comment: Hi @yves, Yes that is exactly what I mean by a Cycle Graph. A graph that is one cycle with all vertices participating to the cycle.

Comment: Now, I understand the problem you want to detect, but I don't think it has been treated already.  the [mathematical components library](https://math-comp.github.io) has something similar, which I use in my own developments, but I already know the graph to be functional (each node has exactly one output edge).  In that case, the graph is describe by a function from a finite type into itself and the property is described by the notation `fcycle`.